# How to detect changes in a UIImageView and change a Boolean when this happens

Tags: swift

I'm using `UIPresentationController` to prevent the user from accidentally closing a `UIViewController` presented modally if the user has made any changes. Everything works as it should when it comes to UITextFields since I detect the changes with `.editingChanged`. A sample code is shown below. I have an `UIImageView` where the user can change to provide a profile photo. I can enable the save button (`rightBarButtonItem`) once the user has uploaded an image using didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo in UIImagePickerController but that would not prevent the UIViewController from closing accidentally. Ideally, I would like to change the value of the hasChanges var but it is a get-only property.

```
var hasChanges: Bool {
    guard let customer = customer else { return false }
    
    if
        firstNameTextField.text!.isNotEmpty && firstNameTextField.text != customer.firstName
        // additional textfields etc…
    {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
    
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    // If our model has unsaved changes, prevent pull to dismiss and enable the save button
    let hasChanges = self.hasChanges
    isModalInPresentation = hasChanges
    saveButton.isEnabled = hasChanges
}

@objc func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    if hasChanges {
        // The user tapped Cancel with unsaved changes
        // Confirm that they really mean to cancel
        confirmCancel(showingSave: false)
    } else {
        // No unsaved changes, so dismiss immediately
        sendDidCancel()
    }
}



@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if hasChanges {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    }
}



func setupTextFieldDelegates() {
    let textFields = [all the textfields are included here]
    
    for textField in textFields {
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you have to create a custom UIImageView, where you have to create a delegate variable and a protocol with a method and need to override the image variable.

when override the image variable you have to call the delegation method inside the didSet method of variable.

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView{
    override var image: UIImage?{
        didSet{
            delegate?.didChangeImage()
        }
    }
    
    var delegate: ImageViewDelegate?
    
}

protocol ImageViewDelegate {
    func didChangeImage()
}
```

Next in your ViewController set the delegate.

```
class ImageViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: CustomimageView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.delegate = self
    }
    

}
```

If you use the outlet from the storyboard, make sure to provide the custom class name to outlet. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Your code is very useful and does a portion of what I intended. I figured out a different way to accomplish the task by adding another boolean.